# Using Interia / Vue.js within XAMPP

Tags: laravel, apache, xampp, vuejs3, inertiajs

After following the Laravel bootcamp that creates a small project called chirps, which works perfectly while using artisan on windows, when I try to access via apache in XAMPP, the inertia uris as defined below are not recognized in the browser

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});
```

This is config in my xampp/apache/conf/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "{path}/public"
    ServerName {projectName}.local
    ServerAlias {projectName}.local
    <Directory {path}/public>
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The app.blade.php file is loaded as expected but as soon as you try to go to login / register it does not recognise them when running via apache, but work fine when running under artisan. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: i simply wouldn't use xampp

Comment: `AllowOverride none` means all the (important!) instructions in https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/public/.htaccess are being ignored.